# Can't edit/review layout files in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

When I double click to open an android layout *.xml file in android studio i get an AssertionError: null in Event Log from Android studio and the layout editor doesn't open.

This doesn't happen in every project, and started to happen in projects there were already working fine, here the log error

```
null
java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.MultiResourceRepository.setChildren(MultiResourceRepository.java:47)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.MultiResourceRepository.<init>(MultiResourceRepository.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ModuleResourceRepository.<init>(ModuleResourceRepository.java:57)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ModuleResourceRepository.create(ModuleResourceRepository.java:87)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ProjectResources.create(ProjectResources.java:174)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getProjectResources(AndroidFacet.java:996)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ProjectResources.get(ProjectResources.java:163)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ProjectResources.get(ProjectResources.java:154)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ModuleSetResourceRepository.create(ModuleSetResourceRepository.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ProjectResources.create(ProjectResources.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getProjectResources(AndroidFacet.java:991)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ProjectResources.get(ProjectResources.java:163)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ProjectResources.get(ProjectResources.java:154)
    at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ConfigurationManager.create(ConfigurationManager.java:120)
    at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:99)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowForm.setFile(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowForm.java:234)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:322)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2003)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:289)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:347)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:672)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:642)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:701)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:526)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:349)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Now I can't edit/review layout files in Android studio, does anybody knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: having the same problem since i updated AS..

Comment: I notice that removing the project from studio and deleting *iml files and then importing again, it will allow to edit, but once you close and restart the problem comes back.

Comment: I'm having this problem also

Answer (score 1):

Just delete this line from your activity:

```
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_splash"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Android Studio**
 Issue [124715](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=124715)

***Solutions :*** 
You do that by editing the "studio.exe.vmoptions" file in this path: Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin.  Remove the line that says "-ea".

You can refer [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=124715) link